# Find area outside circle $r=7$ and inside cardioid $r=6+7\sin \theta$

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

So this is the question I have problem dealing with.

I know that firstly I need to equate $7$ and $6 + 7\sin \theta$ to get the intersection. 
And then I am supposed to apply the formula..

But I am not sure how to find out the bounds and how to subtract the areas to get the answer

Comment: and what if I am asked for the area of the region lying inside r=6 and outside r=4-3sin theta.

Comment: I guess it is the same way but the subtraction will be different

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to look at the graphs to get an idea of it. [Wolfram can help here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%20%2B%207sin%28theta%29%2C%207%20polar). Once there, you notice that there are two places where the circle and the cardioid intersect. That may be calculated by doing:

$$
f(\theta)=7\ ;\ g(\theta)=6+7\sin(\theta) \\
f(\theta) = g(\theta) \\
\theta_0 \approx .14334
$$

Then, by symmetry, the area that is both inside the cardioid and outside the circle is the same from $\theta_0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to the corresponding angle $\pi - \theta_0$. Doing the integral of the difference of the functions:

$$
2\frac{1}{2} \int_{\theta_0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(g(\theta)^2 - f(\theta)^2)\ \mathrm{d}\theta = \\
\int_{\theta_0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (g(\theta)^2 - f(\theta)^2)\ \mathrm{d}\theta = \\
\int_{\theta_0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} ((6+7\sin(\theta))^2 - 7^2)\ \mathrm{d}\theta = \\
\int_{\theta_0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (36 + 84 \sin(\theta) + 49 \sin(\theta)^2 - 49)\ \mathrm{d} \theta \\
\int_{\theta_0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (36 + 84 \sin(\theta) - \frac{49}{2} \cos(2\theta) + \frac{49}{2} - 49)\ \mathrm{d} \theta
$$

By evaluating then we get an area of approximately $103.18$ units.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes it does help! Thank You!

Comment: But I think that the formula you applied is wrong? It should be 1/2 times integral of f^2(theta) against theta?

Comment: @John I think I've got it right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The area is given by
$$\frac12\int_{\sin^{-1}\frac17}^{\pi-\sin^{-1}\frac17}
[(6+7\sin \theta )^2-7^2]d\theta=50\sqrt3+\frac{23}2\cos^{-1}\frac17
$$